# Power series with radius of convergence 2 that diverges at both -2 and 2?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm looking for a real power series that has radius of convergence 2 but diverges at both 2 and -2. Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Options:

1. Try expanding a function like $\frac{1}{(x+2)(x-2)}$ at the origin.
2. Get a series with radius one $\sum x^n$. This one diverges at $1$ and $-1$ dilate its domain by replacing $x$ by $x/2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum x^i$ has radius of convergence 1 and diverges at $\pm 1$, so just replace $x$ with $\frac x2$, obtaining $$\sum_{i=1}^n 2^{-i}x^i.$$